# Dynamically connect to an endpoint from a ZeroMQ client

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

My client built with **pyzmq**, will connect to a service that will provide it with the correct address it needs to connect to. It might do this several times, each time having to connect to a different worker.

What I have created until now, based on the zguide, is a simple broker that will accept connections from clients on a *frontend* port and then it will connect with one of the workers and make a question (right now its just a random choice of yes and no). If the client replies with 'yes' then my idea was to let the client know that that specific worker is ready and have it connect directly to the worker.

In the examples that I have seen clients mostly connect to a single server or broker once. What would be the best way to connect with an address given to me on runtime potentially multiple times?

Comment: You might decide to update your post, so as to **specify** all the such components, that build together **The "Best"-ness metric** first, to indicate what you prefer, what you penalise and thus clarifying what is better than something else and **to allow others to design, test and compare against a given common target.**

Comment: The reason I chose to not post my specific client and worker code is because I am at the process of learning zeroMQ thus they are probably of no use, moreover by best I mean a simple way of just achieving those connections on runtime, at the moment I am in no way good enough in 0MQ, let me see if the above edit will make things clearer though.

Comment: Connecting to different queues is a easy as: `context = zmq.Context()`
`socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)` `socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")` so it would be useful to have your code. From my view it looks so trivial to connect to different destinations during runtime I don't really see the question, just do it...

Comment: Glad for both comments. Ad dearn44 -- you might have realised, there was **no explicit push to post an MCVE** ( while the StackOverflow Community Netiquette promotes to do so ). There was, on the other hand, **an explicit request to state parameters that a design MUST meet to be The Best one.** This ought be given to make the Question have a sense. Ad 576i -- **Yes & No**. Once going into deeply distributed low-latency design, the costs of setup / connect / tear-down owerheads may and do grow beyond a threshold of diminishing returns and start to become destructive parts of the modus-operandi.